# Lastlog filling up very quickly because of Podman

Tags: logs, podman

Particularly I notice this when doing podman builds, my /var/log/lastlog file will fill up very quickly robbing my /var directory of any remaining space.  Apparently it has something to do with sparse file creation.

The Podman user documentation says that if you are doing a useradd, there is a switch to limit the logging, but I am not explicitly performing a useradd, so I can't find any way to limit the logfile being added to and I will quickly run out of space on /var.

I also do not have permission on /var so I cannot delete this file, which adds another layer of non-niceness to this problem.